# How to remove the "Reset" text from reset button in HTML form

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use a custom image for a reset button on a form but can't get the default "Reset" text to disappear when I create a class and insert the background image. I'm using a table to create the form and here is the code for this part of the form:

```
        <tr>
            <td colspan=6>
                <input type="reset" class=cancelButton>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

It seems pretty straight simeple and straight forward.  Here is my CSS custom class code:

```
.cancelButton {
    background-image: url(cancel.jpg);
    width: 160px;
    height: 35px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

This is what I get:

[image]

Any assistance would be appreciated.  This is for an assignment so I can't take shortcuts.

Comment: Do you want the *reset* appears when you click on the cancel the order?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use background images to convey information. CSS is for *presentation*.

Use a regular image, and a button element instead of an input element (since a button element can contain the image).

```
<button type="reset"><img src="cancel.jpg" alt="Cancel"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `value=""` to your input tag

```
<input type="reset" value="" class=cancelButton>
```